# Peculiar behavior with imageview and checkbox in gridview

Tags: android, checkbox, imageview, simplecursoradapter

I get data(`imagepaths`) from sqlite, so I used `simplecursoradapter` to show images in a `gridview`. In each gridview item, it contains an imageview and a checkbox as shown in the below code. Here my first problem is images seem to be changed their positions whenever the gridview is scrolled and gets settled in their own places after some time which seems weird. I think these problems are caused because the views are reused when scrolled.

Second problem is when few `checkboxes` are checked and scrolled, the checkboxes values are changed i.e., if I check on few checkboxes of the imageviews and scroll down to select more, the other `checkboxes` are checked. Can someone please help me on avoiding this issue?

```
public class ImagesScreen extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       .......................

       .......................
          gridView.setAdapter(imagecursorAdapter);

    }

    }
```

**Adapter class:**

```
public class ImageCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

        private int layout;
        private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
        private Context mContext;
        ViewHolder vh;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,String[] from, int[] to)  {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to,0);
            this.layout = layout;
            mLayoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mContext = context;
        }

        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {     
            View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
            return v;
        }

        public void bindView(final View v, final Context context, Cursor c) {
            final int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
            final String imagepath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("paths"));
            vh = new ViewHolder();

            vh.imageview = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            vh.checkBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            vh.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
       Log.d("ischecked",""+isChecked);                             
                }

            });
            File imgFile = new File(imagepath);
            if(imgFile.exists()){

                Bitmap imageBitmap = decodeFile(imgFile);
                vh.imageview.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }

        }

     static class ViewHolder{

            public ViewHolder(){}

            public ImageView imageview;
            public CheckBox checkBox;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please look in to this: http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-adding-actionbar-navigation.html and http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/04/milti-selection-listview-android-with.html

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar Yeah. Here you have used  holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]); to ensure that no checkboxes are jumbled. But in my case where do I need to add that code because I am using SimpleCursorAdapter? Please suggest.